# Something is wrong with my xsl for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

When I have the incorrect for each, or what I presume to be incorrect, it displays an empty graph. When I have what I presume to be the right for each, it doesn't display any formatting.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="cat-department.xsl" type = "text/xsl" ?>
<department xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <foo:person>
        <title>Assistant Professor of Sports and Recreation</title>
        <firstname>Hobbes</firstname>
        <lastname>Cat</lastname>
        <office>Cougar Center, KM 103</office>
        <phone>765-123-5678</phone>
        <email>hobbes@cat.net</email>
    </foo:person>
    <foo:person>
        <title>Professor of Feline Economics</title>
        <firstname>Felix</firstname>
        <lastname>The Cat</lastname>
        <office>Main Building, KO 170</office>
        <phone>765-555-1234</phone>
        <email>felix@cat.net</email>
    </foo:person>
    <foo:person>
        <title>Professor of Feline Gastronomy</title>
        <firstname>Garfield</firstname>
        <lastname>Cat</lastname>
        <office>East Building, KE 255</office>
        <phone>765-123-4321</phone>
        <email>garfield@cat.net</email>
    </foo:person>
    <foo:person>
        <title>Adjunct Instructor</title>
        <firstname>Kingston</firstname>
        <lastname>Cougar</lastname>
        <office>Main Building, KO 210D</office>
        <phone>765-789-3456</phone>
        <email>cougark@iu.edu</email>
    </foo:person>
</department>
```

And here is my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
    <h2> The last names Sorted are</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Phone </th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="department/foo:person">
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="lastname"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="office"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="email"/></td>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I put random gibberish in the for each, it displays an empty graph. When I put what I thought was correct, it displays the text from my xml file but there isn't any formatting.

Comment: Your namespaces are a mess.

Comment: Mind elaborating? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I think you need to bind your foo prefix to a namespace uri.

Comment: Debugging tip: look at the actual HTML that's generated; don't just look at how the HTML is rendered in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You've omitted the `<tr>...</tr>` in the `for-each`.

```
</tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="department/foo:person">
    <tr>                                 <!-- HERE -->
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="lastname"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="office"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="email"/></td>
    </tr>                               <!-- AND HERE -->
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in the XSLT.

1. Namespaces `xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/"` and `xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org"` have not been declared in the XSLT which are required since you are accessing element `foo:person`.
2. For the header row of the table, `<th>Office</th>` is missing which would result in one column not having a header in the html output.
3. Inside the `for-each`, you need to add a `<tr>....</tr>` for every `foo:person` data else the output table will be a mess.
4. The HTML page heading talks about "Sorted" names but there is no sorting applied. You need to use `xsl:sort` to achieve that. I have added sorting on `lastname`.

Below is the updated XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org"> <!-- Namespaces added -->
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2> The last names Sorted are</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                      <th>Title</th>
                      <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                      <th>Office</th> <!-- Added header element -->
                      <th>Phone </th>
                      <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="department/foo:person">
                        <xsl:sort data-type="text" order="ascending" select="lastname" /> <!-- sorting applied on lastname -->
                        <tr> <!-- Added row for the data -->
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="lastname"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="office"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="email"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

HTML Output

[image: HTML Output]

Comment: If the answer has worked for you, could you please accept the answer. [How to accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)